# 2 issues on scroll bar in table

Tags: php, html, css

Got 2 questions regarding a table which output is below:

[image]

Question 1:

The table height is 500px, yet what I don't understand is that it looks like the content underneath which doesn't belong to the table is displayed within the table because of the scroll bar that goes so that down that it looks like the content underneath the table rows are in the table. So my question is how can I get the scroll bar to appear only if the 500px is met, rather than showing it straight away as it is doing now? How do I get the content (select box, heading, etc) be displayed underneath the table rather than in the table as it is doing in the screenshot

Question 2:

How can I get the scroll bar to be clipped on the side of the table? At the moment it is clipped just underneath the last column meaning it is taking up some of the last column's space and hence why table columns are not matching.

Below is html code of table:

```
            <table id="tableqanda" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="30%" class="question">Question</th>
        <th width="8%" class="option">Option Type</th>
        <th width="6%" class="noofanswers">Number of Answers</th>
        <th width="8%" class="answer">Answer</th>
        <th width="6%" class="noofreplies">Number of Replies</th>
        <th width="6%" class="noofmarks">Number of Marks</th>
        <th width="12%" class="images">Images</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="tableqanda_onthefly_container">
    <table id="tableqanda_onthefly" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <?php
          foreach ($arrQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {
        echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="30%" class="question">'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="8%" class="option">'.htmlspecialchars($arrOptionType[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="6%" class="noofanswers">'.htmlspecialchars($arrNoofAnswers[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="8%" class="answers">'.htmlspecialchars($arrAnswer[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="6%" class="noofreplies">'.htmlspecialchars($arrReplyType[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL; 
        echo '<td width="6%" class="noofmarks">'.htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL; 
        echo '<td width="12%" class="images">'.htmlspecialchars($arrImageFile[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
?>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <h4>PARTICIPATING STUDENTS</h4>

    <p>
    <strong>Number of Participating Students:</strong> <?php echo $studentnum; ?>
    </p>

    <p>
    <strong>Current Participating Students:</strong>
    <br/>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select name="students" id="studentslist" size="10">

    <?php
if($studentnum == 0){
    echo "<option disabled='disabled' class='red' value=''>No Students currently in this Assessment</option>"; 
}else{
    while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {

    echo "<option disabled='disabled' value='$dbStudentId'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
}
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </p>
```

Below is CSS:

```
#tableqanda_onthefly_container
{
    width:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height:500px;
}

#tableqanda_onthefly
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    clear:both;
}


#tableqanda, #tableqanda_onthefly{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}       

#tableqanda{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
    float:left;
}

#tableqanda td { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#tableqanda th{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I want my table to remain as a scrolling table with fixed headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

For question 1, try setting the overflow-y property to auto. This way the scrollbar will only be displayed once the table exceeds 500px in height.

So something like:

`overflow-y:auto;`

instead of

`overflow-y:scroll;`

**ORIGINAL POST:**

To answer your second question, you can just add the heads of the table as another row:

```
<div id="tableqanda_onthefly_container">
<table id="tableqanda_onthefly" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <th width="30%" class="question">Question</th>
    <th width="8%" class="option">Option Type</th>
    <th width="6%" class="noofanswers">Number of Answers</th>
    <th width="8%" class="answer">Answer</th>
    <th width="6%" class="noofreplies">Number of Replies</th>
    <th width="6%" class="noofmarks">Number of Marks</th>
    <th width="12%" class="images">Images</th>
</tr>
    <?php
      foreach ($arrQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {
    echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td width="30%" class="question">'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td width="8%" class="option">'.htmlspecialchars($arrOptionType[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td width="6%" class="noofanswers">'.htmlspecialchars($arrNoofAnswers[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td width="8%" class="answers">'.htmlspecialchars($arrAnswer[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td width="6%" class="noofreplies">'.htmlspecialchars($arrReplyType[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL; 
    echo '<td width="6%" class="noofmarks">'.htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL; 
    echo '<td width="12%" class="images">'.htmlspecialchars($arrImageFile[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
```

This way the scroll bar should be put at the very right, not underneath anything. The reason it wasn't before was because you had two different tables with independent widths.

Comment: The reason I set my table as I did was because I want a scrolling table with fixed headers. If I change the table to what you mentioned then I don't get the fixed headers for a scrolling table, so I can't use this. My fault, I should of mentioned that I wanted a fixed headers scrolling table

Comment: Updated with answer for question 1.